# background-image doesn't load

Tags: css, background, background-image

I have a problem with the background-image property.
I want to insert the image of a film roll in the background of the `div` `scena`, but `background-image:url(img/rullino.png);` doesn't show anything.

When I write it inline with Firebug on Mozilla, then it works.

Someone understand why this happens?

```css
/* tag */

body,html{
 background-color: grey;
 font-family: 'Existence Light', arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.8em;
 height:100%;
}

p {
 word-wrap:break-word;
}

/* ======= Generale sezioni ======= */

.sections{
 min-height: 100%;
}

/* ======= Entry-section ======= */

#entry-logo img{
 margin: 10% 0 0;
}

#entry-section #go-down{
 margin-top: 9%;
 text-align: center;
}

#entry-section i{
 content:"\f078";
 color:white;
}

/* ======= film-section ======= */

#film{
 height:100%;
}

#film > .container{
 height:100%;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 width:100%;
}

.container > #rullino {
 height:20%;
 background-color:red;
}

body #film .container #rullino .scena {
 background-image: url(img/rullino.png);
 background-color: #00ff00;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height:100%;
 width:15%;
 float:left;
}

#rullino img{
 max-height:70%;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <section id="entry-section" class="sections">
    <div class="container">
     <div id="entry-logo">
      <img src="img/logo.png" width="100%" alt="Un Autre Chien Andalou">
     </div>
     
    </div>
    <div id="go-down">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
     </div>
   </section>
   <section id="film" class="sections">
    <div class="container">
     <div id="rullino">
      <div id="scena1" class="scena">
       <p>scena1</p>
      </div>
      <div id="scena2" class="scena">
       <p>scena2</p>
      </div>
      <div id="scena3" class="scena">
       <p>scena3</p>
      </div>
      <div id="scena4" class="scena">
       <p>scena4</p>
      </div>
      <div id="scena5" class="scena">
       <p>scena5</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are your HTML and CSS file in same folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with this image of a puppy, and it worked for me :  "[http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8.*CB312176604*.jpg](http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg)".

So it seems like it could be your image path. Rather than "img/rullino.png", try "./img/rullino.png" or an absolute path to your image, so that it checks your current folder for the image.

Also, just a tip for readability + cleaner CSS - If you want the image as the bg of all the divs with the class '.scena' you'll only need to do this:

```
.scena {
    background-image: url(img/rullino.png);
    background-color: #00ff00;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:100%;
    width:15%;
    float:left;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nothing! I did the same thing with the puppy and then it works, but with the path it doesn't work. 
I tried with different paths but nothing. If I write the code inline in Firebug it works. I am speechless.

Comment: Just tried with  `background-image:url(../img/rullino.png)` and it worked!
@nreddy216 it was a problem of path, as you said: the image and the css live in subdirectories and need `(../img)` in the path.
Bye and thanks